# How can I get my user inputted numbers to be read all on one line to be placed into a 2D array?

Tags: java, arrays, formatting, user-input

Basically, I have this program. It is not completed yet but the gist of it is that it is a grade book with user input grades for a number of students they enter. They also enter the number of grades. What I'm struggling with is how to get the program to read the numbers after the first one on the line. The numbers being read is under the name "scores". So I want it to read it as:

1 2 3 4 (it just would read 1 and 5 right now)

5 6 7 8 (I want it to read them all)

Here's my code if it helps:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class SeventhAssignment {
public static double scores[][];

public static void main(String[] args) {
    DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat(".00");

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    int students;

    System.out.print("Enter number of students");
    students = input.nextInt();
    if (students <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Both numbers must be positive");

        System.exit(0);
    }

    int grades;

    System.out.print("Enter number of grades");
    grades = input.nextInt();
    if (grades <= 0) {
        System.out.println("Both numbers must be positive");

        System.exit(0);

    }

    double[][] arr = new double[students][grades];
    System.out.println("Enter " + students * grades + " grades: ");
    int i;
    int j;
    for (i = 0; i < students; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < grades; j++) {

            Scanner scores = new Scanner(System.in);
            arr[i][j] = scores.nextInt();
        }

        for (i = 0; i < students; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < grades; j++) {

                System.out.print(arr[i][j] + "  ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}

public double getMinimum() {
    double lowGrade = scores[0][0];
    for (double studentGrades[] : scores) {
        for (double grade : studentGrades) {
            if (grade < lowGrade)
                lowGrade = grade;

        }
    }
    return lowGrade;
}

public double getMaximum() {
    double highGrade = scores[0][0];
    for (double studentGrades[] : scores) {
        for (double grade : studentGrades) {// if grade is greater than
                                            // higherGrade, assign to higher
                                            // grade
            if (grade > highGrade)
                highGrade = grade;
        }

    }
    return highGrade;// returtn higher grade
}

public static double getAverage(double setofGrades[]) {
    double total = 0;// Initializing total
    // sum of grade for one student
    for (double grade : setofGrades)
        total += grade;
    // return average of grade
    return (double) total / setofGrades.length;

}

public void outputGrades() {
    System.out.println("The grades are:\n");
    System.out.println("         ");// for alignment

    for (double test = 0; test < scores[0].length; test++)
        System.out.printf("Test %d", test + 1);
    System.out.println("Average"); // student average column heading

    for (double student = 0; student < scores.length; student++) {
        System.out.printf("student %2d", student + 1);

        for (double test : scores[(int) student])// output student grades
            System.out.printf("%8d", test);
        // call method getAverage to calculate students average grade
        // pass row of grades as the argument to getAveerage
        double average = getAverage(scores[(int) student]);
        System.out.printf("%9.2f\n", average);
    }

}
}
```

Thanks ahead for any help you guys can bring!

Comment: read one line and split it if you know the logical order.

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear to me. Try adding some more explanation of what is happening right now and what you actually want.

Comment: The only user inputted grades being read are the first ones in the line. I want all the numbers to be read instead of having to do a new line every time.

Comment: @user3354072 You don't have to create a new `Scanner` for reading the `scores`. You can use `input`.